# Unix equivalent PowerShell code using R to fetch data from a web portal

Tags: r, powershell, unix

Through my R code running on Windows, I run the following PowerShell code saved in a file named `FileName.ps1` to fetch data from a web portal.

```bsh
curl 'https://some_site.com/solr/some_folder/select?q=*:*&wt=csv' -L -u username:password --location-trusted -b cookie-jar.txt > OutputFilename.csv
```

```r
system2("PowerShell", args=c("-file", "C:\\FolderName\\FileName.ps1"))

df <- as.data.frame(read.csv("OutputFilename.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-16LE"))
```

How would I implement this in R running on an Unix server. Powershell for Unix is not installed in the Unix server.

Comment: Isn't the part you need to work out how to run in R the logic contained within `FileName.ps1`? You're showing R here (or a shell script), not PowerShell.

Comment: Since you're apparently using a Windows port of cURL rather than the PowerShell builtin alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` you can simply put the `curl` commandline in a bash script and run `system2("/usr/bin/bash", args=c("/path/to/your.sh"))`.

Comment: @alroc Most likely the first line is in his PowerShell script, while the other 2 lines are his R code. I edited the question to make the 2 snippets distinguishable from each other.

Comment: That helped me overcome the bottleneck. I am new to unix and I learnt something useful today.